# Viewing Serilog logs on Asp.Net MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, serilog, stackexchange.exceptional

I'm using Serilog in my Asp.Net MVC project. (If it matters, I'm using the SQL Server Sink).

Previously, I installed StackExchange.Exceptional, and its near so easy to use as Serilog, but it have with a great feature: We can access the logs via web interface, accessing an "exceptions.axd" configured via web.config.

I see Serilog is a "low level logger", it can be used in web, desktop, consoles, etc... then obviously it doesnt comes with this ".axd" function.

There is some Serilog extension, or project with a simple axd handler like this, where we can install and just works like in StackExchange.Exceptional?

Comment: close voters care to explain the why... so I can try fix the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've implemented a [simple log viewer](https://github.com/mo-esmp/serilog-ui) 
 for Serilog and SQLServer sink. It will come in handy if you are using ASP.NET Core.